# "SHOW TABLES LIKE '*sub_string*' " not working with HIVECONTEXT

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

```
hive_context.sql("use caz_applied_ana")
```

Here is the code I am using in jupyter notebook. This is the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o332.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.13] failure: ``in'' expected but identifier 
like found

show tables like 'caz*'
```

Comment: can you add your complete code and full stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

In **Spark 1.6** you can do the following.

First select all the table names from the database and then filter the table names using `like` operator

```
df = sqlContext.tables("database_name").filter("tableName like '%caz%'")
```